# Swift 4.2 Add/Remove buttons with UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uibutton, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to add an `UIButton` to every cell in my `UICollectionView` when a button (outside of the `UICollectionView`) is pressed and then remove them when it's not.

Basically, a `boolean` if true - show/add, else hide/remove. This is my `cellForItemAt`. I also tried adding it to `willDisplay cell`.

```
let btnItemDelete = UIButton()
btnItemDelete.tag = indexPath.row
btnItemDelete.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnItemDeleteClick), for: .touchUpInside) //Selector works
btnItemDelete.frame = CGRect(x: cell.bounds.width-22, y: 2, width: 20, height: 20) //Creation works
btnItemDelete.setImage(deleteImage, for: .normal) //Image works



if (isEdit) {
    //Add or Show
    cell.addSubview(btnItemDelete)
}
else {
    //Delete or Hide
    btnItemDelete.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

When running this, `isEdit` is initially set to false and the buttons do not show up. After clicking the button to change the boolean, the buttons appear. When clicking the button to set the boolean back to false, the buttons stay. I am figuring it's something with `btnItemDelete.removeFromSuperview()` - is there a different approach to do this? I figured I can't hide/show them because it's just going to keep adding a new button to the cell on every reload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to add to

`cell.contentView` not the `cell`

By this

```
btnItemDelete.removeFromSuperview()
```

you remove a button on the fly that's not added , instead you need

```
cell.contentView.subviews.forEach {
  if $0.tag == 12 {
     $0.removeFromSuperview()
   }
}
```

---

I think the best approach is to add the button previously on the cell layout then manage it's appearance like

```
cell.myButton.isHidden = !isEdit
```

Comment: `$0` removed the entire cell's content, but I decided to just add it on the storyboard and hide/show it like that. I'll give your second option the credit.

Comment: all subviews has 0 tag , so you need to give the button other separate tag

Comment: you may want that tag to be indexPath.row , so you may extend the button with another attribute or go smoothly as you did with the other alternative